# "If Any Contains Any" (DbExpressionBinding requires an input)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to build a simple search where I pass a list of keywords. But soon as I add the "any contains keywords" as a list instead of a string I get:

`"DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType."`

I have extended `IQueryable<Inspector>` with:

```
 public static IQueryable<Inspector> Search(this IQueryable<Inspector> qry, List<string> keywords)
 {
    return from i in qry
           where
             i.LastName.Any(x => keywords.Contains(i.LastName)) ||
             i.FirstName.Any(x => keywords.Contains(i.FirstName)) ||
             i.City.Any(x => keywords.Contains(i.City)) ||
           select i;
 }
```

And when I call it I use:

```
return qry.Search(keywords).ToList();
```

How should I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're trying to get at this:

```
return from i in qry
    where keywords.Contains(i.LastName) ||
        keywords.Contains(i.FirstName) ||  
        keywords.Contains(i.City)
    select i;
```

This will return you any records where the FirstName, LastName, or City is in your keyword list.

Comment: my thoughts exactly. The where is an implicit any().