# Count the number of times the letter 'o' is in a field using LINQ and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, azure

I am trying to use Linq to determine the number of occurrences of a letter within a string inside a SQL field on a table.

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and SQL Azure.

So if I have

```
The Quick Brown Fox jump over
```

If I was searching for the letter `o`, it would return `3`

Any ideas?

Comment: Pseudo code: `orgStr.length - orgStr.ReplaceAll("o","").length`

Answer (score 3):

What about this :

```
string s = " The Quick Brown Fox jump over";
int cnt= s.Count(x => x == 'o');
```

Comment: Now try this against a SQL table, it fails

DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType

Comment: Error must be related to your collection. check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411651/if-any-contains-any-dbexpressionbinding-requires-an-input

Answer (score 3):

You could use LINQ `Count`:

```
var stringToSearch = "The Quick Brown Fox jump over";
var count = stringToSearch.Count(c => c == 'o');
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it that is case-insensitive:

```
string input = "The Quick Brown Fox jump over";

char target = 'o';

var count = input.Count (c => char.ToLower(c) == target);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
string s = "The Quick Brown Fox jump over";
Console.WriteLine(s.Split('o').Count() - 1); //3
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/blmqwY)</kbd>.

Comment: Why `-1` while calculating count?

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Because 3 `o` characters divide `4` piece a string.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty OP didn't mentioned any case-sensitive issue.

Comment: Now try this against a SQL table, it fails

DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found that will work with SQL is:

(field.Length - field.Replace(search, "").Length) / search.Length

Answer (score 0):

THis will also work

```
string teststr = "The Quick Brown Fox jump over";
int aaa = teststr.Where(x => x.Equals('o') ).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string s = ("The Quick Brown Fox jump over").ToLower();
int count = s.Count(a => a == 'o');
```